# Jumplist support for putty for different session on the windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, putty

I was wondering if anyone has figured out how to do jumplist support for different putty sessions sessions on the windows 7 taskbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My research, posted in the comments to Diago's answers, led me to this blog entry: [**PuTTY with Windows 7 jumplist support**](http://www.infi.nl/blog/view/id/43/PuTTY_with_Windows_7_jumplist_support)

[image]

It's by the same guy(s) who submitted the [wish list entry](http://www.putty.nl/wishlist/win7-jumplists.html) and the [patch](http://speeltuin.infi.nl/~daniel/putty/).

There is a [**pre-compiled version**](http://www.infi.nl/file/download/file_id/294) of Putty with jumplist support at the bottom of the post. Works fine for me on Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bits.

---

Support for Windows 7 jumplists has been added to the official version 0.61 (released on 2011-07-12, more than 4 years after the 0.60!).

> Support for Windows 7's new user interface features. The new Aero window management
>   should now play nicely with PuTTY's complicated window resize handling, 
>   and Windows 7 jump lists are now supported so you can launch saved sessions directly from the taskbar.

The Release Notes can be read [here](http://lists.tartarus.org/pipermail/putty-announce/2011/000016.html) and the binaries can be downloaded [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

Comment: ya for pre-compiled

Comment: I read the wish list entry and it seems to be fixed in r9046. So it is now in the trunk, but not in the official binaries.

Answer (score 3):

Jump-list support is a feature of the application and therefore can only be implemented by the developers. The application needs to have the ability to keep track of recently used files, and there is a specific developer API set that can be used to support the feature.

I can't recall if Putty is still actively being developed however you will most likely need to make a feature request for this. As pointed out by [Snark](https://superuser.com/users/10131/snark) there is a request for this [here](http://www.putty.nl/wishlist/win7-jumplists.html) already, and the actual code is available [here](http://speeltuin.infi.nl/~daniel/putty/) if your willing to compile yourself.

Comment: This request in the Putty Wish List: http://www.putty.nl/wishlist/win7-jumplists.html

Comment: Actually the code already exists, see here: http://speeltuin.infi.nl/~daniel/putty/ . Someone who can compile the Putty source code could generate an executable with jumplist support.

Comment: guess this will have to do until it's officially released...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a fully pre-compiled version that works with Windows 7 that you can find [here](http://fahhem.com/putty/) and I've been using it for months with no issues. It hasn't crashed or failed to provide a JumpList.

The jump-list is opt-in and rather unobtrusive.

(Disclaimer: I wrote the page)