# Make initial PuTTY configuration window larger

Tags: putty, window

In [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY), I'd like to know how to make the initial configuration window larger. I've got like 50 devices saved and it's such a tiny box to scroll in. I'd prefer to make it the full length of the screen to search for my saved configurations.

So; this is not to be confused with the window size of an actual SSH session; but just the initial window where you can scroll through your saved sessions before you open one.

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible, but I do know that the fork of PuTTY known as KiTTY has a significantly larger configuration window **and** can create folders to sort your configuration entries into.

Comment: Thinking laterally: you can make a catalog of [session shortcuts](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-startsess) to directly connect to each of your saved sessions. Then you are limited by the Explorer window which you can make any size you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not possible with standard PuTTY.

You should look into modified versions of PuTTY or extensions like:

- [SuperPutty](https://github.com/phendryx/superputty)
- [KiTTY](http://kitty.9bis.com/)
- [PuTTY Session Manager](http://puttysm.sourceforge.net/)

In case you're using PuTTY on Windows 7, you might also be interested in the jumplist [integration](https://superuser.com/a/112101/36744) of the latest version.

Comment: +1 for being bolder than I was and actually answering instead of commenting (and being 100% sure about it).

Comment: Great, Putty Session Manager does the trick. http://sourceforge.net/projects/puttysm/

I'll also check out Kitty.

Do you have a personal preference?

Comment: @JamesR404 I looked into this myself a while ago and just ended up with PuTTY again. The forks didn't have the latest PuTTY features and it just didn't feel right. I currently use plain PuTTY and just heavily rely on Jumplists. Maybe I'll take this as an opportunity to check out alternatives again :)

Answer (score 4):

1. You can try [Kitty](http://kitty.9bis.com/), a fork of Putty. It still does not have resizable config window, but the session list is much bigger.
2. Consider using an external remote connections manager. I had a similar problem, not only with Putty sessions, but also with Remote Desktop connections and decided to use [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/) to manage all my remote connection information. It offers full integration with Putty, it can use existing session definitions but you can also store the settings in mRemote's XML config file.

EDIT: Sorry I did not notice Oliver Salzburg's earlier answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this connection in kitty to change the size of the screen problem solved.

http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Config+Box&theme=PuTTY

To modify the size of the configuration box window (for non standard dpi settings) just add this:

[ConfigBox]
windowheight=800

Regards!